# Describe all possible reduced row echelon forms of:

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I tried looking it up.. don't remember seeing anything like this in the prior section in book.. I'm not sure what it even means by describe.. or how to do it with variables... don't have a clue what to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a): If you divide the first row by $a$, you get a $1$ as the first element. Divide next row by $d$ and you get $1$ as the first element at this row also. Now one can eliminate one of these $1$'s by subtracting the rows. And so on..

Comment: I see. I guess that will suffice as an answer?